# Android Studio: id of plain text does not work

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am a real rookie so this is probably a real rookie mistake!

but... I have a problem. I am working on an inventory app and i put in a plain text with the id: editTextItemName

But when i use it in my code:

```
class AddItemActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.add_item)

        
        val database = getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        database.edit().apply {
            putString("savedItemName", editTextItemName)
        }.apply()
    }
}
```

"editTextItemName turns to red and it says "Unresolved reference: editTextItemName"

How do i fix this?

My answer to the answer: I put this into my code and now i have an new error:
e: C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\StorageManagementTheThird\app\src\main\java\com\example\storagemanagementthethird\AddItemActivity.kt: (20, 40): Type mismatch: inferred type is EditText but String? was expected

Comment: Which part of the code throws that error, please update your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> e:
> C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\StorageManagementTheThird\app\src\main\java\com\example\storagemanagementthethird\AddItemActivity.kt:
> (20, 40): Type mismatch: inferred type is EditText but String? was
> expected

**Root cause**

[SharedPreferences.Editor.putString(String, String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#putString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) receive two `String` parameters, but in your code you pass `editTextItemName` is an instance of `EditText` as the second parameter, so the compiler throws the error.

**Solution**

Change your code to

```
val database = getSharedPreferences("database", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
database.edit().apply {
    putString("savedItemName", editTextItemName.text.toString())
}.apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to get access to your editTextItemName view? In your code it is not clear. For example are you using kotlin synthetic? If no you should add this on your code in order to get access to your view:

```
val editTextItemName: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editTextItemName)
```